# Calculate frequency of all possible combinations of substrings in a vector

Tags: r, string, combinations, frequency

I have a vector like `strings` and want to calculate the frequency of each of the values separated by the delimiter "|" and combinations of them, like the `result` below in R.

```
strings <- c('a', 'a|b', 'a|c', 'a|b|c|d')

# Calculate how many times 'a' is present, how many times 'a' and 'b', denoted 'ab', are present, etc. My goal is to be able to identify which combinations of substrings are most common.

result <- data.frame(substring = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'bc', 'bd', 'abc', 'abd', 'abcd'),
                     frequency = c(1, .5, .5, .25, .5, .5, .25, .25, .25, .25, .25, .25))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, obtaining every subset of a given set is known as the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set).

There is a package `rje` that contains the function `powerSet` that produces this for a given vector.

Below we have a function that will take a vector (with the assumption it has the form indicated by the OP (i.e. pipe-delimited and lower case letters)) as input, generate the power set, and finally determine the frequency of each substring.

```
library(rje)

getFreqs <- function(v) {
    idx_lets <- Reduce(union, sapply(strsplit(v, ""), function(x) {
        match(x, letters, nomatch = 0)
    }))
    
    do.call(rbind, lapply(powerSet(letters[idx_lets])[-1], function(x) {
        data.frame(substring = paste(x, collapse = ""),
                   frequency = ifelse(length(x) > 1,
                                      length(Reduce(intersect, sapply(x, function(y) {
                                           which(grepl(y, v))
                                       }))),
                                      sum(grepl(x, v))) / length(v)
        )
    }))
}
```

Here is an example:

```
getFreqs(strings)
   substring frequency
1          a      1.00
2          b      0.50
3         ab      0.50
4          c      0.50
5         ac      0.50
6         bc      0.00
7        abc      0.25
8          d      0.25
9         ad      0.25
10        bd      0.25
11       abd      0.25
12        cd      0.25
13       acd      0.25
14       bcd      0.25
15      abcd      0.25
```